# How to filter for multiple identifier values in AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, jmespath

When filtering multiple identifier values in the AWS CLI, the results are the same with or without a period. Is the period optional?

The official references does not mention that it can be omitted.

- [AWS Command Line Interface: Filtering for multiple identifier values](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-usage-filter.html#:%7E:text=To%20filter%20for%20multiple%20identifiers%2C%20you%20use%20a%20multiselect%20list%20by%20using%20the%20following%20syntax%3A)
- [JMESPath: SubExpressions](https://jmespath.org/specification.html#subexpressions)

The output of the following two queries will be the same:

```bash
aws ec2 describe-instances \ 
  --query 'Reservations[].Instances[].[InstanceId,InstanceType]'
```

Returns

```json
[
    [
        "i-0f74894a273e9a76f",
        "t2.micro"
    ],
    [
        "i-007598b789e08ca19",
        "t2.micro"
    ],
    [
        "i-0e2defdabf5771dfa",
        "t2.micro"
    ],
    [
        "i-07db1ecca76653ae5",
        "t2.micro"
    ]
]
```

And

```bash
aws ec2 describe-instances \
  --query 'Reservations[].Instances[][InstanceId,InstanceType]'
```

Returns

```json
[
    [
        "i-0f74894a273e9a76f",
        "t2.micro"
    ],
    [
        "i-007598b789e08ca19",
        "t2.micro"
    ],
    [
        "i-0e2defdabf5771dfa",
        "t2.micro"
    ],
    [
        "i-07db1ecca76653ae5",
        "t2.micro"
    ]
]
```

Why is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two are equivalent because the result of `Reservations[].Instances[]` is a JSON array.
So you can either do a [Multiselect](https://jmespath.org/tutorial.html#multiselect) on top of this array `[].[InstanceId,InstanceType]` or do a [projection](https://jmespath.org/tutorial.html#list-and-slice-projections) of the fields in the array itself `[][InstanceId,InstanceType]`.

So, indeed on a simple JSON:

```json
{
  "foo": [{
    "bar": "baz",
    "qux": "quux"
  }]
}
```

These expressions:

- ```
  foo[].[bar, qux]
  ```
- ```
  foo[][bar, qux]
  ```

are the same and both yields

```json
[
  [
    "baz",
    "quux"
  ]
]
```

---

This said, you should probably favour the first form `foo[].[bar, qux]`, not only because this is [the syntax used in the tutorials](https://jmespath.org/tutorial.html#multiselect), but also because it will work in all the situation, so, also, if the parent JSON node is an object and not an array.

Here is a example where the two syntax are not identical, given the JSON:

```json
{
  "foo": {
    "bar": "baz",
    "qux": "quux"
  }
}
```

- The expression:

  ```
  foo.[bar, qux]
  ```

  will work as expected and return

  ```json
  [
    "baz",
    "quux"
  ]
  ```
- While

  ```
  foo[bar, qux]
  ```

  will just error out and gives you nothing in return.

Comment: `foo[*].[bar,qux][0]` and `foo[*][bar,qux][0]`, does the different result mean that in the former case the projection of the later [0] is aborted by the creation of a new array element by [MultiSelect](https://jmespath.org/tutorial.html#multiselect)?

Comment: Honestly this comment if worth a question all by itself, but in short, in JMESPath, a projection does not end by itself, [you have to stop it](https://jmespath.org/tutorial.html#pipe-expressions). Since the a multiselect is not a projection, it makes then sense that you have a different behaviour.

Comment: ^- because, in the first case, you are selecting `[0]` out of the projection, and in the other in a "regular" JSON array.

Comment: So, for example, `foo[*].bar[0]` and `foo[*].[bar,qux][0]` seem to have the same form, but does the former project `bar[0]` on each element of the array, while the latter performs `[0]` on the result of projecting MultiSelect on each element of the array?

Comment: You probably want to read what the documentation explain in the [_pipe expression_](https://jmespath.org/tutorial.html#pipe-expressions) chapter. Extract: _If you tried `people[*].first[0]` that you just evaluate `first[0]` for each element in the people array, and because indexing is not defined for strings, the final result would be an empty array, `[]`._

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I still have a little bit of Projections and MultiSelect that I don't understand, and since there is a character limit in the comments section, I will ask the question again from the Quesitons.